# How to make Checkbox List in ASP.Net core web api using Entity Framework

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a form with a List of checkboxes along with some other inputs in Visual Studio Code:

```
<form name="CarServ" id="myForm">
            <div>
                <label>CarModel:</label>
                <input type="text" id="model" size="65" name="CarModel" placeholder="Enter Car Model" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Car Number:</label>
                <input type="text" size="65" id="num" name="CarNumber" placeholder="Enter Car Number" required >
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Contact number:</label>
                <input type="text" size="65" id="cnum" name="ContactNumber" placeholder="Enter your contact number" required>
            </div>


            <div id="service" class="opt">
                <label>Type of service:</label>
                <input type="radio" name="TypeOfService" id="t1" value="Waterwash"required>
                <label for="t1">Waterwash</label>
                <input type="radio" name="TypeOfService" id="t2" value="Fullservice" required>
                <label for="t1">Fullservice</label>
    
    
            </div>
            <br/>

            <div class="check">
    
                <label>Addons:</label>
    
                <input type="checkbox" name ="SelectedCheckboxes[]" value="10%off First service visit" id="10%off First service visit">
                <label for="10%off First service visit">10%off First service visit</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedCheckboxes[]" value="10%off Waterwash"  id="10%off Waterwash">
                <label for="10%off Waterwash">10%off Waterwash</label>


                <input type="checkbox" name ="SelectedCheckboxes[]" value="Free AC Inspection" id="Free AC Inspection">
                <label for="Free AC Inspection">Free AC Inspection</label>


            </div>  

    
            <div class="dropd">
                <label>Select State:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name ="SelectState" id="select1">
                        <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">--SELECT--</option>
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select State</option>
                        <option value="option1">Tamilnadu</option>
                        <option value="option2">Kerala</option>
                        <option value="option3">Karnataka</option>
                        <option value="option4">Maharastra</option>
                    </select>   
            </div>
            
            <div class="dropdcontent">
                <label>Select City:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name ="SelectCity" id="select2">
                        <option value="option1">Select State</option>
                        <option value="option1">Chennai</option>
                        <option value="option1">Coimbatore</option>
                        <option value="option1">Madurai</option>
                        <option value="option2">Select State</option>
                        <option value="option2">Trivandrum</option>
                        <option value="option2">Kochi</option>
                        <option value="option2">Kollam</option>
                        <option value="option3">Select State</option>
                        <option value="option3">Bangalore</option>
                        <option value="option3">Mysore</option>
                        <option value="option4">Select State</option>
                        <option value="option4">Mumbai<option>
                        <option value="option4">Pune<option>
                  </select>     
            </div>
            <br/>
                    
            <button id="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <input type="reset" value="RESET" onclick="clearreset()" name="reset" />    
        
    
        </form>
        <script src="formtoapi.cs"></script>
```

Posting it to WebAPI using FETCH
formtoapi.cs :

```
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit",submitForm);

function submitForm(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(event.target);
  formData.set("SelectState", $("#select1 option:selected").text());
  formData.set("SelectCity", $("#select2 option:selected").text());
  /*
  var checkstring="";
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkstring=checkstring+checkboxes[i].value+";"
  }
  formData.set("checkk",checkstring);
  */

  var json = {};
  formData.forEach((value, key) => json[key] = value);

  fetch("https://localhost:7032/api/CarServiceForm/submit-form",{
    mode:"cors",
    method:"POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(json)

  })
  .then(response =>{
    if(!response.ok){
      throw new Error("HTTP error"+response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data=>{
    console.log("Success:",data);
  })
  .catch(error=>{
    console.error("Error:",error);
  });
}
```

I got Three models with many-to-many relation :

FormData.cs :

```
public class FormData
    {
        public int FormDataId { get; set; }
        public string CarModel { get; set; }
        public string CarNumber { get; set; }
        public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfService { get; set; }
        public List<string> SelectedCheckboxes { get; set; }
        public string SelectState { get; set; }
        public string SelectCity { get; set; }
        public ICollection<AddonFormData> Addons { get; set; }



    }
```

Addon.cs :

```
public class Addon
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Checkboxes { get; set; }
        public ICollection<AddonFormData> FormDatas { get; set; }

    }
```

AddonFormData.cs :

```
public class AddonFormData
    {
        public int AddonId { get; set; }
        public Addon Addon { get; set; }
        public int FormDataId { get; set; }
        public FormData FormData { get; set; }
    }
```

FormDbContext.cs :

```
public class FormDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public FormDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }  
        public DbSet<Addon> Addons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FormData> FormDatas { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<AddonFormData>()
                .HasKey(af => new { af.AddonId, af.FormDataId });
            builder.Entity<Addon>().HasData(
                new Addon { Id = 1, Checkboxes = "10%off First service visit" },
                new Addon { Id = 2, Checkboxes = "10%off Waterwash" },
                new Addon { Id = 3, Checkboxes = "Free AC Inspection" });

            builder.Entity<AddonFormData>()
                .HasOne(af => af.Addon)
                .WithMany(af => af.FormDatas)
                .HasForeignKey(af => af.AddonId);
            builder.Entity<AddonFormData>()
                .HasOne(af => af.FormData)
                .WithMany(af => af.Addons)
                .HasForeignKey(af => af.FormDataId);


        }

    }
```

Controller class :

```
 public class CarFormController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly FormDbContext _db;
        public CarFormController(FormDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        [HttpPost("submit-form")]
        public IActionResult SubmitForm([FromForm] FormData formdata)
        {

            _db.FormDatas.Add(formdata);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }

    }
```

and while using onSubmit I get this error on console :

```
Addons
: 
["The Addons field is required."]
CarModel
: 
["The CarModel field is required."]
CarNumber
: 
["The CarNumber field is required."]
ContactNumber
: 
["The ContactNumber field is required."]
SelectCity
: 
["The SelectCity field is required."]
SelectState
: 
["The SelectState field is required."]
SelectedCheckboxes
: 
["The SelectedCheckboxes field is required."]
TypeOfService
: 
["The TypeOfService field is required."]
status
: 
400
title
: 
"One or more validation errors occurred."
traceId
: 
"00-54a3f12fccfc7a7b099a7a62df9ab998-927935095fc65748-00"
type
: 
"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"
```

**"SelectedCheckboxes"** => Since I pass them as an array, I declared them as List in **FormData.cs** but I hope I'm wrong. My Plan is to pass data from html to web API to store it in a database and then retrieve them back to the console using GET but I'm stuck in step1.

Imma bit confused how to create a model for this.

Comment: Please don't delete your innitial question  even it was solved

Comment: And  you don't show all codes related with sending data from your view to controller,I tried on my side as below ,it works well

Comment: @RuikaiFeng I shouldn't have removed the error from the question , I'll ty to add it back and to answer ur second question, I'm not using a view in here.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error just because this line in your entity:

```
public List<string> SelectedCheckboxes { get; set; }
```

You defined this property for model binding

```
<input type="checkbox" name ="SelectedCheckboxes[]" value="10%off First service visit" id="10%off First service visit">
 <label for="10%off First service visit">10%off First service visit</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedCheckboxes[]" value="10%off Waterwash"  id="10%off Waterwash">
 <label for="10%off Waterwash">10%off Waterwash</label>
```

but it was considered as a navigation property with another "Entity" string,so you got the error

add `[NotMapped]` attribute on this property would fix the error,also,you could create a View Model for modelbinding instead of using the entity directly

```
public class FormDataViewModel
    {
        public int FormDataId { get; set; }
        public string CarModel { get; set; }
        public string CarNumber { get; set; }
        public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfService { get; set; }
        public List<string> SelectedCheckboxes { get; set; }
        public string SelectState { get; set; }
        public string SelectCity { get; set; }
    }

public class FormData
    {
        public int FormDataId { get; set; }
        public string CarModel { get; set; }
        public string CarNumber { get; set; }
        public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfService { get; set; }
       
        public string SelectState { get; set; }
        public string SelectCity { get; set; }
        public ICollection<AddonFormData> Addons { get; set; }
    }
```

[NotMapped] won't affect modelbinding:

[image]

[image]

I don't know why you copy key value pairs from formdata not adding then to json directly,and there seems no codes related with handling check box
,just tried as below :

```
<script>
   document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit",submitForm);

function submitForm(event){
  event.preventDefault();
 
   var json = {};
   const arr = [
  "10%off First service visit",
  "10%off First service visit"
]
  json['SelectState']='State'
  json['SelectCity']='City'
  json['SelectedCheckboxes']=arr;

  fetch("https://localhost:7282/Home/TestPage",{
    mode:"cors",
    method:"POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(json)

  })
  .then(response =>{
    if(!response.ok){
      throw new Error("HTTP error"+response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data=>{
    console.log("Success:",data);
  })
  .catch(error=>{
    console.error("Error:",error);
  });
}
</script>
```

Since you are accepting json value,add [FromBody] if you are not trying with ApiController

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help and now should I join those 2 models? FormDataViewModel to Addon.

Comment: and if I add [notmapped] , will I be able to receive the inputs perfectly?

Comment: [notmapped] won't affect model binding,you could checked what i updated

Comment: Just fill your FormData entity with FormDataViewModel ,FormDataViewModel  doesn't have a directly relationship with Addon

Comment: sounds good, Did My FETCH work fine? I hope it got some issues with sending inputs as key, value pair

Comment: Can U update the code with Controller class too? and Did u actually post through fetch or created form in views and then passed the values. I actually got my form in visual studio code and i'm passing it to api which is in visual studio. Im pretty new to this , So your controller class could actually help as a reference

Comment: If you send json data correctly with your former codes,it would work well, I just tried with postman to confirm [NotMapped] won't affect model binding like this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#working-with-the-bytearraymodelbinder

Comment: There's no bussiness logical in my controller, I just tried a minimal example to make sure the error was fixed,if you have any problem with bussiness codes,please show your codes in your controller to let us know what you want to do....

Comment: Also,if  you got error with your fetch,please show the error so that we could try to reproduce the error

Comment: Ive updated my code with controller class. I did use [NotMapped] attribute , and after updating database I couldnt find SelectCheckboxes field in there. I basically want to get the inputs including selected checkboxes from user and store in a database and then retun the stored values in database back to the console on success. Multiple user can select multiple options thats the reason why I went for a many-many relationship.

Comment: and I jus added the error which I get on fetch. I havent added the FormViewModel as u told me to due to the fact that im not working with views on my project. Is that the problem? should I add FormViewModel?

Comment: Since you already stored checkbox items in db,there's no need to create SelectCheckboxes  file ,you could learn how to read and save related data

Comment: Check these documents first:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data     https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager